# How to get VSI connected/disconnected status which displayed on portal from API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

On softlayer customer portal, we can see VSI connected/disconnected status from Device detail page.
But which API can retrieve this status?
It seems different from Softlayer_Virtual_Guest_Power_state.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

that value come from the associated monitor to the VSI, if the monitor is not able to collect information you will get the disconnect status.

you can use this method:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getLatestNetworkMonitorIncident

This returns the network monitoring event COMPLETED or SERVICE FAILURE. if you service failure so the device is in disconnected status.

Regards

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!